# ReactContext function to add items to cart (addcartItems) is not working

Tags: reactjs

In a simple web app my goal is to add  a addCartItems function , so when the user clicks on the + icon on the product it would have to add that item into an array. im using react context , and initialized the cartItems to an empty array and in the Image component (which is the item being added) i have
i have come up with the following function in the context of the app

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from "react"
const AppContext = React.createContext()

function AppContextProvider(props){
    const [allPhotos,setAllPhotos] = useState([]);
    const [cartItems,setCartItems] = useState([]);
 //removed code that imports photos 
  
     function addCartItems(id){

        let updatedCartItems = allPhotos.map(photo=>{
            if(photo.id===id){
                cartItems.push(photo)
                return {
                    cartItems
                   
                }
               
            }
   
                 return cartItems
        })
       
        setCartItems(updatedCartItems)
      console.log(cartItems)
     }
   
    return(
       <AppContext.Provider value={{allPhotos, toggleFavorite,addCartItems}}>

           {props.children}
       </AppContext.Provider>

   )

}

export {AppContextProvider,AppContext}
```

And in the Image component where i execute it i have written the following

```
  function Image({className, img}) {
    const [ hovered,setHovered] = useState(false)
    //const [isFavorited,setIsFavorited] = useState(false)
    const {toggleFavorite,addCartItems} = useContext(AppContext)

    function heartIcon() {
        if(img.isFavorite) {
            return <i className="ri-heart-fill favorite" onClick={() => 
             toggleFavorite(img.id)}></i>
        } else if(hovered) {
            return <i className="ri-heart-line favorite" onClick={() => 
              toggleFavorite(img.id)}></i>
        }
    }
    

    //const heartIcon =  hovered &&   <i className="ri-heart-line favorite" 
    //onClick={() => toggleFavorite(img.id)}></i>
    const cartIcon =  hovered &&   <i className="ri-add-circle-line cart" onClick={()=>addCartItems(img.id)}></i> 

    return (
        <div className={`${className} image-container`}
             onMouseEnter={()=>setHovered(true)}
             onMouseLeave={()=>setHovered(false)}
        >
            <img src={img.url} className="image-grid"/>
               {heartIcon()}
              {cartIcon}
        </div>
    )
}
```

When I check the console.log it first outputs the item i clicked on, when i click again on another item it prints a bunch of undefined, if I check console.log(cartItems.length) it will print 1 the first time and 24 the next. What Am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your help ( GITHUB repo https://github.com/NaveenDK/ecommerce-front and the branch is `solution1-addtocart`

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that according to the documentation, `Array.push()` will **return** the new length of the array, **not the array itself**. This is why it is printing 1 instead of returning the array.

You have 2 options there, create a new reference to the array or use the `Array.concat()`, that accepts both **values and arrays** as a second argument and returns the array.

Reference: [Array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), [Array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)